# Ввод данных в БД с использованием чекбоксов

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, mvvm

Пытаюсь сделать проект в паттерне MVVM и возникла проблема при добавлении записей в БД. Суть в том чтобы выбирать при помощи чекбоксов блюда, которые необходимо добавить в заказ через чекбоксы. Потом это через логику добавляется в смежную таблицу многие ко многим.

```
        List<Dish> _dishes = new List<Dish>();
    private RelayCommand _checkedCommand;
    public RelayCommand CheckedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _checkedCommand ?? (_checkedCommand = new RelayCommand(x =>
            {
                if (SelectedDish != null)
                {
                    SelectedDish.IsChecked = !SelectedDish.IsChecked;
                    if (SelectedDish.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        Dish dublicate = _dishes.FirstOrDefault(x => x == SelectedDish);
                        if (dublicate == null)
                        {

                            _dishes.Add(SelectedDish);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }));

        }
    }
```

Код из XAML:

```
        <DataGrid ColumnWidth="*" Name="Menu" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDish}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Dish}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Блюдо" Binding="{Binding Title}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Стоимость" Binding="{Binding Price}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Время приготовления" Binding="{Binding Time}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Command="{Binding CheckedCommand, ElementName=VM}"></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Добавить" Command="{Binding AddOrder}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3"/>
    <Button Content="Отмена" Command="{Binding CloseAdd}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
</Grid>
```

По факту работает это так, что сам заказ добавляется, а его содержимое нет...
[image: Вот так это выглядит в запущеннос состоянии]

Так реализованно добавление заказа в логике:

```
        private RelayCommand _addOrder;
    public RelayCommand AddOrder
    {
        get
        {
            return _addOrder ?? (_addOrder = new RelayCommand(add =>
            {
                CafeContext context = new CafeContext();
                Order neworder = new Order { CookerStatus = false, WaiterStatus = false, FlunkyId = 1, WaiterId = 2 };
                context.Orders.Add(neworder);
                context.SaveChanges();

                var list = context.Orders.ToList();
                var last = list.LastOrDefault();
                int idlast = last.Id;
                foreach (var dish in _dishes)
                {
                    context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"INSERT INTO Dish_Order Values({idlast},{dish.Id})");
                }

            }));
        }
    }
```

А вот структура БД:
[image: Диграмма БД]

Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Comment: Просьба не судить строго, только начал изучать паттерн

Comment: 1 Столько информации не несет никакой пользы. Вам проще включить отладчик чтобы увидеть не сохраняются ли данные или вообще из формы не попадают в вьюмодель (пустой _dishes), чем нам угадать где же оно там теряется. 2  Что за странная логика CheckedCommand? Есть добавление в список `_dishes.Add`, но нет удаление из этого списка. Да и проще без команды. Вы же биндите `IsChecked` и как бы этого достаточно - а потом при сохранении просто выбрать с `IsChecked=true`